# how to get Listview item text in android

Tags: android

how to fetch item text of list in android, can i do this in android, i am using list adapter and want to get each item text in list for further comparing. any help is appreciable. i have this code

```
    mLv_PGA.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View convertview, int position,
                long arg3) 
        {
            //String item = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //on item click event here

            if(Globals.checkWifiavailability(getActivity().getApplicationContext()))
            {
                PGAViewHolder vh   = (PGAViewHolder) convertview.getTag();
                  vh.mTitle.getText();

                  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PGASubListActivity.class);
                  intent.putExtra("rss", 
                                     Sections.URL_PREFIX+
                          Sections.PGA_SECTION_NEWS_RSS.get(vh.mTitle.getText().toString())+
                          Sections.URL_POSTFIX);
                  intent.putExtra("title",vh.mTitle.getText().toString());
                  intent.putExtra("section",mTag);
                  startActivity(intent);

            }
            else
            {
                //just show the alert incase of wifi not connected
                 Globals.showAlert(getActivity());
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you have a custom adapter, you can manage your textview within your adapter. It is a better way to control your rows inside your adapter. You can set your clicked position in activity and control the textview on clicked row inside getView method.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on if you're using your own Layout or not. If you're using a default layout, you can get the text of your `ListView` by:

```
String text = (TextView) convertView.getText();
```

Else, you'll have to find the View in your layout first, and then use getText(), like:

```
String text = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.the_id_of_your_textview)).getText();
```

Comment: i want to show specific item in toast, how can i achieve this ?

Comment: Simply get the text the way I posted, and then call Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1):

I will expand a little on Digvesh's answer as I think thats fine.

The `convertview` parameter for the `onItemClick` method is the view thats being clicked. So from this you should be able to find the `TextView` which you want to get the text of by using the `findViewById` method. When you have text view you can use the `getText` method to retrieve its contents. So the following should work.

```
TextView textView = (TextView) convertview.findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
String myText = textView.getText();
```

Comment: Dreagen i do this like u said, but why i used  this textview? i only want to get text of any specific item and then compare this item text with my tag which is string and after comparing this do something. can i show any item text in toast, kindly show that code, and thanks

Comment: The text you want to get must be in a text view. (Look at the layout for your list view to find what the text views id is).If you post your layout for your list view I might be able to make my answer more specific for you

Comment: yes i get your point. if i find further difficulties then i will post my xml and supporting code for you, thanks once again

Comment: mHolder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
       String myText = (String)mHolder.mTitle.getText();
       Toast.makeText(mContext, myText.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

this is code i use but get nothing in toast kindly help

Comment: The basics seem correct. myText is already a string so you don't need myText.toString() in your toast, also instead of casting mHolder.mTitle.getText() to a string you should do String myText = mHolder.mTitle.getText().toString();

Comment: to clear up some confusion with text views etc use the following code: String text = ((TextView)(convertview.findViewById(R.id.title))).getText().toString();  Toast.makeText(mContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();